When must a space generated by compacts also be generated by Hausdorff compacts?
Cross-posted to MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475934/.

I'm interested in comparing $k_1$-spaces,
spaces whose topologies are witnessed by
their compact subspaces, and $k_3$-spaces,
spaces whose topologies are witnessed by their
compact and Hausdorff subspaces.
This distinction is moot for Hausdorff spaces
(hence, the literature generally only refers
to $k$-spaces),
and more generally for $k_1H$
spaces for which
every compact subspace is Hausdorff. So I'm
interested if these $k_i$-space
properties are equivalent for
a weakening $KC$ of the $k_1H$
property, where each compact subset is closed
in the space.
Every compact space is a $k_1$,
and every compact $k_1H$ space is
Hausdorff, so I considered a compact $KC$
space that isn't Hausdorff:
Steen-Seebach's example #99:
$\omega^2\cup\{\infty_x,\infty_y\}$ where points
of $\omega^2$ are isolated, neighborhoods of
$\infty_x$ contain all but finitely-many elements
of each row, and neighborhoods of $\infty_y$
contain all but finitely-many rows.
It turns out this space is $k_3$: consider a
non-closed subset $A$, which must either be
missing a limit at $\infty_x$ or at
$\infty_y$. If $A$ is missing a limit at
$\infty_x$, it must contain some subset
unbounded in a row $\omega\times\{N\}$
of $\omega^2$; in this
case, the missing limit is witnessed by
the compact Hausdorff subspace
$(\omega\times\{N\})\cup\{\infty_x\}$.
Similiarly, if $A$ is missing a limit at
$\infty_y$, it must contain some subset
$range(f)$ where $f:\omega\to\omega^2$
satisfies $\pi_y(f(n+1))>\pi_y(f(n))$,
that is, the vertical component of
$f$ is increasing for each $n<\omega$;
in this case, the missing limit is
witnessed by the compact Hausdorff
subspace $range(f)\cup\{\infty_y\}$.
More generally, I'm using a theorem
that any sequential KC space is $k_3$:
similarly, the only other non-Hausdorff
compact $KC$ construction
I know of offhand,
converging a sequence of these Steen-Seebach spaces to a point,
is sequential and therefore $k_3$.
So my specific question is: does there exist a compact
$KC$ space (or more generally, a $k_1$ KC
space) that is not $k_3$ (necessarily, not sequential nor $T_2$)?
(Note that the
square of the one-point compactification of the rationals
is an example
of a weak Hausdorff compact space that is not
a $k_3$ space.)

Under the weak Hausdorff condition, the notion of $k_3$-space is equivalent to $k_2$-space (spaces with topology determined by continuous maps from arbitrary compact Hausdorff spaces), which is the most commonly studied notion of k-space/compactly generated space.  That may make it easier to find counterexamples.
